# Javadoc with Equations?

Tags: math, javadoc

I'm only familiar with the no-frills javadoc generator, however I'd like to include some mathematical equations in my javadoc (rather than constantly referencing another document).

Is there a convenient option to do something like include/properly render LaTeX (most preferred - then I could just cut-n-paste) or MathML tags?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/).

It's blazing fast, free, and supports embedded LaTeX.

Comment: I poked around that a bit; the LaTeX option seems to only be supported when generating ps/pdf documentation.  Is there an option to generate the conventional style javadoc (which I'm very fond of) with, say, images generated from the LaTeX embedded?  I can handle a little configuration, but I'm not looking to program my documentation generator.

Comment: Doxygen will also embed LaTeX in generated HTML documentation using images.  I confirmed this using Doxygen on my code just a minute ago.

Comment: Broken link: current one is https://www.doxygen.nl/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) or [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/) could be your solution.  They're both JavaScript libraries, so you'll have to find a way to add them into your javadocs pages.

Comment: hrm, any suggestions for starter info on customizing javadoc output?  as in, where I might begin to even think about how to add js to what's produced by the javadoc tool?

Comment: @Carl, [this blog post](http://zverovich.net/2012/01/14/beautiful-math-in-javadoc.html) describes how to include the MathJax JavaScript in the HTML files.  It seems to be that's all that's required.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't done it personally, there are ways to create your own using the Doclet or Taglet API to create your own Doclet or Taglet. Several of these have already been done according to a quick search providing one such example http://www.ohloh.net/p/latextaglet

If you're feeling daring enough the latextaglet project is open source, so you might be able to further adapt it to your needs.